Old Black & white film where jet fighter crashes in a foreign country
I cannot figure out what the name of a movie I saw within the last 10 years. It was an older, black and white film from the 1950's or possibly 1960's.
It started out with a 50's style jet fighter crashing in a foreign country. The pilot got out alive, and proceeded to move out, and he came across the enemy's fox holes, or trenches, and he got down in them, and I believe he killed an enemy or two, as he walked along the trench and that is all I remember.
I think it was either Glenn Ford, Richard Widmark, or possibly Frank Sinatra but probably not. It was a fairly famous actor of the time period.
It came on American movie classics or Turner classic movies pretty sure, one day when I was home sick in bed. 
Gandalf jogged my memory,and the actor could have been William Holden. I checked his list if movies,and none of the titles sounded like a war movie,I looked in the 50 or 60's section,but didn't watch many trailers to make sure.
I also remember the plane looked like a f-89 scorpion, I remember the large fuel tanks on the wings when it crashed. All the tips I've posted I'm fairly certain,happened in the very beginning of the movie. The pilot didn't seem to go far, to get into the trench,after crashing. Then I think I fell asleep,since I was sick.

There was a movie made in 1950'sabout the Korean war, but there were actually 3 men at one point, all crashing sequentially in F-86 Sabres. What day approximately were you home sick?

Thank you Gandalf, although the hunters looks like an awesome movie and I believe I will even watch it now that I saw the trailer,but it is in color. But you did jogg my memory, and I thought of some more things things that I will edit in my above statement. You asked when I watched this, and I believe it was 8-10 years ago.

I have added an edit to the answer. It contains clips of F9f Panthers, which are similar to F-89's, but the film was once again, in color.

Thanks @gandalf , it turns out it was bridges at Toko Ri. I have that movie, and I watched the beginning before,since I thought that the parts I remembered were in the beginning,and did not see what I remembered, duh, well that's because it was towards the end, so after taking your advise,just watched the whole movie,and there it was, the parts I remembered,thank you so much for your thoughts.

@MikeB. If one of the answers is correct, please approve it (by clicking on the check mark next to it). This effectively resolves the question.

The Hunters (1958) starred Robert Wagner, Lee Phillips, and Robert Mitchum in a fighter pilot movie about a complicated love triangle set against the backdrop of the Korean War.
The three are F-86 Sabre pilots who are shot down behind North Korean lines during a dog-fight. They fight their way back to friendly lines, at one point ambushing and killing a North Korean patrol, and eventually resolve their differences.
It showed on Turner Classic Movies on June 2, 2015 as part of a tribute to Dick Powell, who directed.


Another possibility is The Bridges at Toko Ri (1954). Starring William Holden and Grace Kelly, the film was notable for its "futility of war" stance, and won the Academy Award for special effects.  Adapted from the James Michener novel of the same name, it blended real footage from aircraft carriers and aerial scenes of Grumman F9F-2 Panthers with large scale models.
Lt. Bruebaker (Holden) is shot down over Korea and fights it out with a rescuer in a ditch at one point.
Once again, this flick appears to be color, although some of the actual footage is very drab and might be seen as black and white.

